# GitHub Actions Checkout with LFS (Private Repo)

Tags: github-actions, artifactory, git-checkout, git-lfs

I am storing large files in JFrog Artifactory and rest of the code in GitHub. I am trying to use GitHub Actions Checkout to get the Git Repo code as well as files from the Artifactory.

Since my artifactory is private, I need to use credentials to authenticate which are different than what I use for GitHub login. How can I pass my Artifactory credentials to GitHub Actions Checkout?

I am trying the GitHub Actions checkout as below:

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    lfs: true
```

Comment: See https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-jfrog-cli.